# Spider Aggression: Creating A Simple Behavioral Model

Tags: netlogo

**UPDATE**

Thanks Luke C & JenB. Here's my revised code. I just converted the females to "killer" by turning her territory to a different color (green to blue) if a male wanders into her territory. If any male happens to be on a blue colored patch, he dies. It seems that the male who initially triggers the conversion does not get eaten immediately, which is what I want. He can be eaten if he doesn't get out of her blue territory on the next tick. Then, any subsequent males are eaten immediately.

Also, I am exploring some cool things with the BehaviorSpace tool, like how many ticks it takes for all the males to be eaten in a number of runs.

The only loose ends are creating a graph window that displays the number of males over time (ticks) and a report window(s) with the number of nonkiller/killer females.

**ORIGINAL POST**

I would like to model a behavioral system of wolf spiders with the following rules:

- Females are stationary
- Males move around
- If any male encroaches within a certain radius of a female, that female       becomes a “killer” two ticks later
- Any males within a “killer” female’s territory is eaten and taken out of the population
- The simulation ends when all males are eaten
- All females are “non-killers” at setup

End goals of the model:

- How many ticks does it take for all of the males to be eaten?
- Are there any ‘non-killer’ females in the population at the end of the simulation?

Here is what I have so far. The parts I am struggling with are setting up the female territories, converting non-killer females to killer females when a male enters her territory, accounting for/taking out eaten males, reporting the duration of the simulation in ticks and if any non-killer females remain at the end.

```
breed [females female]
breed [males male]

to setup
  clear-all
  reset-ticks
  ask patches [set pcolor white]
  setup-females
  setup-males
end

to setup-females
  create-females 15 [
    set shape "spider"
    set color 15
    set size 25
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor]
    ask females [move-to one-of patches with [not any? females in-radius 40]
    ; prevents overlapping
    ask patches in-radius 20 [set pcolor green]
    ]
end

to setup-males
  create-males 30 [
    set shape "spider"
    set color black
    set size 20
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor]
    ask males [move-to one-of patches with [not any? males in-radius 10]
    ; prevents overlapping
    ]
end

to go
  move-males
  tick
  if count males = 0 [stop]
end

to move-males
  ask males [
    right random 360
    if random 100 > 49 [forward 1 + random (15 - 1)]
    if pcolor = blue [die]
    ;moves male 1 to 15 units per tick if condition satisfied
    score-females
  ]
end

to score-females
  ask females in-radius 20 [
  if count males > 0 [ask patches in-radius 20 [set pcolor blue]]
  ]
end
```

Comment: Check out the [asking help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to increase the likelihood that your question will get a useful answer. It's usually better to ask about a specific programming problem rather. For example, what exactly isn't working with female territories? What are you expecting to see but not seeing? How have you tried to report simulation duration, and why did that approach fail? If you can narrow down your question into more discrete chunks you'll probably have more luck on here.

Comment: I think your problem is an algorithm problem rather than a NetLogo problem, you don't appear to have worked out exactly the process you want so it is impossible to convert to code. Step through the process in your mind and perhaps draw a flowchart by tick. For example, if the female doesn't become a killer until 2 ticks later, the male that triggered the killer conversion may have left. What if a male is in the territory of 2 different females? How does a female become NOT a killer (after a certain time, after finding any male, something else)? Then come back with a specific step you can't do.

Comment: Now your question is slightly ambiguous: In your original question you write that you want females to turn into killers two ticks after their territory has been invaded. In your revised question it says that you want any invader to die immediately. Both is possible but requires quite different code.

Comment: I don't think I conveyed the rules of the model clearly. Yes, any *subsequent* males will die immediately once a female has become a killer. It's the *first* male(s) who invades her territory and initiates the conversion from normal to killer; he/they get a reprieve for one tick.